# Преобразование String в Date

Tags: java, дата

Не получается преобразовать String в Date

Руководствуясь [этой](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) статьей у меня получилось преобразовать дату, где дни/месяцы/годы передаются в цифрах, но когда, например, название месяца я ввожу в буквах, то выходит ошибка

Работает:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");//задаю формат даты
String dateInString = "29 11 2015";//создаю строку по заданному формату
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);//создаю дату через 
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Не работает:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String dateInString = "28-Nov-2015";
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Выдает:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28-Nov-2015"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java пытается использовать региональные настройки, взятые из системы. А там, скорее всего, используется русский язык. Чтобы парсер понимал английские названия месяцев, его нужно создавать немного иначе:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Или же писать названия месяцев по-русски:

```
String dateInString = "28-Ноя-2015";
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static String dateToString(Date date, String f) {                        
        if (date != null) {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(f, Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
        }
        return null;
    }
```